# 8 month old steer is down

Tags: health

My steer was up and eating fine on Thursday. Friday morning he was lying flat on his side. I got him up to a sitting position, gave him some electrolytes and some antibiotics. He’s not gotten up, he has started having diarrhea. From Friday morning to now, Sunday afternoon, I’ve given him a half gallon of electrolytes every 2 to three hours, by bottle. He was acting better through the night from Saturday to Sunday, and within a couple hours he’s taken a turn for the worse. He’s had two rounds of antibiotics, 60 ml of pepto bismol, and some jump start drench. I don’t know what else to do. I also don’t know how he went down so fast. We have a dairy cow in with him and she is pretty rough with the steers, could he have gone down from stress or internal injury from her? The only reason they were together was so they could all get in the barn in the freezing weather.

Comment: What did the vet say when you asked him?

Comment: Generally, livestock have not been considered "pets" within the scope of this stack.